# Vuejs 3 createApp using firestorePlugin from vuefire getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$unbind' of undefined and no render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuefire

in my vuejs3 app I'm having this simple code in my main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { firestorePlugin } from "vuefire";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(firestorePlugin);



app.mount("#app");
```

maybe I'm not using `app.use(firestorePlugin);` correctly. if I don't do this everything renders perfectly but with this I get this error

```
vuefire.esm.js?0ff2:619 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$unbind' of undefined
    at firestorePlugin (vuefire.esm.js?0ff2:619)
    at Object.use (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:2949)
    at eval (main.js?56d7:9)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1021)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1034)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
    at app.js:925
```

and upon clicking it appears like this where it says *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$unbind' of undefined*

```
 Vue.prototype[unbindName] = function firestoreUnbind(key, reset) {
        this._firestoreUnbinds[key](reset);
        delete this._firestoreUnbinds[key];
        delete this.$firestoreRefs[key];
    };
```

my firebase configs in **firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  authDomain: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  projectId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  storageBucket: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  messagingSenderId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  appId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = firebase.firestore();
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const storage = firebase.storage();
```

any help is appreciated. If there is anything needed please let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the main page https://vuefire.vuejs.org/ you find this note  :

> Note: This version currently supports Vue 2 and Firebase 7. Support for Vue 3 / Composition API and Firebase 8 is on the way.

so try to uninstall the current veriosn and install the next version :

```
 npm install vuefire@next firebase@next
```

Comment: See updated answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/72172017/1459653

Answer (score 1):

**There does not appear to be any updated version of Vuefire that supports current versions of Vue (3) or Firebase (9)**, despite an answer here advising "uninstall the current version and install the next version."

The latest stable version ([vuefire@2.2.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuefire/v/2.2.5)) was published "a year ago" (May 2021) and, as the Feb 2021 answer here indicates, the main page of https://vuefire.vuejs.org/ reads:

*"This version currently supports Vue 2 and Firebase 7. Support for Vue 3 / Composition API and Firebase 8 is on the way."*

The alpha version ([vuefire@3.0.0-alpha.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuefire/v/3.0.0-alpha.2)) was also published "a year ago" (around May 2021) and it "currently supports Firebase 7. Support for Firebase 8 is on the way."